# isValid stays false after form validates

Tags: javascript, reactjs, formik

I have a custom validate function but even when it returns no errors the form is still invalid.

I am passing the following properties to Formik:

```
validate={({ import_files }) => {
    return [...import_files.values()].length === 0
        ? { import_files: 'Please choose a file to import' }
        : {};
}}
onSubmit={onSubmit}
initialValues={{ import_files: new Map([]) }}
```

[Here is a console log of the formik object after validation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l53Ou.jpg)

As you can see the field is touched, it has no errors but `isValid` is still `false`.
Why is the form still invalid?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`isValid` sometimes works unexpected.
You should consider switching your validation check to `errors` array.

If no errors in the `errors` then everything is ok.

```js
const isValid = !Object.keys(errors).length
```

You can find more datails in this open issue: 
https://github.com/jaredpalmer/formik/issues/1116

Comment: This worked, I have already read that issue but it seems to be different to mine, they are setting the field's error to undefined rather than returning an empty error object.

Comment: I had to pickup an old version of Formik and this was the easiest solution.