# Formik - Render ErrorMessage automatically

Tags: javascript, reactjs, formik, yup

I have the following code which you can find here:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-d2fadr?file=src%2FApp.js

```
import { ErrorMessage, Field, Form, Formik } from 'formik';
import React from 'react';
import { Button } from 'react-bootstrap';
import * as Yup from 'yup';

let fieldName = 'hexColor';

const TextInput = ({ field, value, placeholder, handleChange }) => {
  value = (field && field.value) || value || '';
  placeholder = placeholder || '';
  return (
    <input
      type="text"
      placeholder={placeholder}
      onChange={(e) => handleChange(e.target.value)}
      value={value}
    />
  );
};

export default () => {
  const onSubmit = (values, { setSubmitting }) => {
    console.log(values);
    setSubmitting(false);
  };

  return (
    <Formik
      initialValues={{ [fieldName]: 'ff0000' }}
      validationSchema={Yup.object({
        hexColor: Yup.string().test(
          fieldName,
          'The Hex Color is Wrong.',
          (value) => {
            return /^[0-9a-f]{6}$/.test(value);
          }
        ),
      })}
      onSubmit={onSubmit}
      enableReinitialize
    >
      {(formik) => {
        const handleChange = (value) => {
          value = value.replace(/[^0-9a-f]/g, '');
          formik.setFieldValue(fieldName, value);
        };
        return (
          <Form>
            <div>
              <Field
                component={TextInput}
                name={fieldName}
                placeholder="Hex Color"
                handleChange={handleChange}
              />&nbsp;
              <ErrorMessage name={fieldName} />
            </div>
            <Button
              type="submit"
              disabled={!formik.isValid || formik.isSubmitting}
            >
              Submit
            </Button>
          </Form>
        );
      }}
    </Formik>
  );
};
```

I want to know if is it any way to render the `ErrorMessage` element automatically?

The error message should be shown somewhere around the input text.

If you know how, you can fork the StackBlitz above with your suggestion.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Don't really know why `ErroMessage` is not rendering before you submit your form once but you can replace the line `<ErrorMessage name={fieldName} />` by `{formik.errors[fieldName]}` to make it works

```js
import { ErrorMessage, Field, Form, Formik } from 'formik';
import React from 'react';
import { Button } from 'react-bootstrap';
import * as Yup from 'yup';

let fieldName = 'hexColor';

const TextInput = ({ field, value, placeholder, handleChange }) => {
  value = (field && field.value) || value || '';
  placeholder = placeholder || '';
  return (
    <input
      type="text"
      placeholder={placeholder}
      onChange={(e) => handleChange(e.target.value)}
      value={value}
    />
  );
};

export default () => {
  const onSubmit = (values, { setSubmitting }) => {
    console.log(values);
    setSubmitting(false);
  };

  return (
    <Formik
      initialValues={{ [fieldName]: 'ff0000' }}
      validationSchema={Yup.object({
        hexColor: Yup.string().test(
          fieldName,
          'The Hex Color is Wrong.',
          (value) => {
            return /^[0-9a-f]{6}$/.test(value);
          }
        ),
      })}
      onSubmit={onSubmit}
      enableReinitialize
    >
      {(formik) => {
        const handleChange = (value) => {
          value = value.replace(/[^0-9a-f]/g, '');
          formik.setFieldValue(fieldName, value);
        };
        return (
          <Form>
            <div>
              <Field
                component={TextInput}
                name={fieldName}
                placeholder="Hex Color"
                handleChange={handleChange}
              />&nbsp;
              {formik.errors[fieldName]}
            </div>
            <Button
              type="submit"
              disabled={!formik.isValid || formik.isSubmitting}
            >
              Submit
            </Button>
          </Form>
        );
      }}
    </Formik>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

the issue is validation schema. When I changed 6

```
 return /^[0-9a-f]{6}$/.test(value);
```

to 3

```
 return /^[0-9a-f]{3}$/.test(value);
```

and submitted with the initial value, ErrorMessage component is rendered

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To reach your goal, I changed your code as below:

1. Since Formik's default component is `Input`, I deleted your TextInput component as there was nothing special in your component and `handleChange` function.

```js
<Field name="hexColor" placeholder="Hex Color" onChange={(e) => handleChange(e.target.value)}/>
<ErrorMessage name="hexColor" />
```

2. As in mentioned in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60941089/1604503), I changed your submit button condition to determine whether the button is disabled or not:

```js
<Button type="submit" disabled={Object.keys(errors).length}>
  Submit
</Button>
```

You can view my entire solution [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-4mdjng?file=src%2FApp.js).

### Edit

If you want to keep your component, you should pass `props` as you might be missing something important, e.g. `onChange`,`onBlur` etc.

```js
const TextInput = ({ field, ...props }) => {
  return (
    <input
      {...field} {...props}
      // ... your custom things
    />
  );
};

<Field
  component={TextInput}
  name={fieldName}
  placeholder="Hex Color"
  onChange={(e) => handleChange(e.target.value)}
/>
```

[Solution 2](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ogyzug?file=src%2FApp.js)